# One single inner class to handle all JButton actionEvents?

Tags: java, swing, actionevent

I have just one `JFrame` and then hierarchically I created a few `JPanel`s to finally make my buttons and text fields and other components to go where I wanted. I have just one class `MainWindow` with bunch of panels and buttons and text fields bound to them. Also all components are fields of the `MainWindow` class.

Now I created just one inner class `ButtonHandler` which implements `ActionListener`, and I am just checking `e.getSource() == <name of the button>`.

And then I call appropriate method to handle that. Here's few code

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == submit) {
            AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
            if (helper.addRecord(personName.getText(),
                    itemName.getText(),
                    itemCost.getText(),
                    consoleArea)) {
                consoleArea.append("Record added to database...\n");
                itemName.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }
        if(e.getSource() == clear) {
            itemName.setText("");
            itemCost.setText("");
            personName.setText("");
            consoleArea.append("All items cleared...\n");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == exit) {
            frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(e.getSource() == search) {
            AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
            helper.search(months.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
                    year.getText(), consoleArea);
        }
        if(e.getSource() == calculate) {
            AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
            helper.calculate(months.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
                    year.getText(), consoleArea);
        }
        if(e.getSource() == deleteFile) {
            AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
            helper.deleteFile(months.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
                    year.getText(), consoleArea);
        }
    }

}
```

And I have a `registerListerner()` method that registers (name implies).

```
private void registerListeners() {
    itemName.addFocusListener(new SelectAllHandler());
    itemCost.addFocusListener(new SelectAllHandler());
    personName.addFocusListener(new SelectAllHandler());
    year.addFocusListener(new SelectAllHandler());
    submit.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    clear.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    exit.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    search.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    calculate.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    deleteFile.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
}
```

So, is this a good idea? I am kind of new to Swing and basically GUI in general. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, look at your code. Do you think it is well structured, easily understandable and easy to maintain? I don't think so. Better use different classes for different actions to be done. This way it's easier for you to handle your own code if changes have to be performed.

Comment: You might want to look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Answer (score 0):

No it would be much better to have separate handler for different actions:

```
class SearchHandler implement ActionListener {
    public SearchHandler(AppHelper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        helper.search(months.getSelectedItem().toString(), year.getText(), consoleArea);
    }
}
```

Same for other actions, and then create a unique helper to construct your handlers:

```
AppHelp helper = new AppHelper();
submit.addActionListener(new SubmitHandler(helper));
clear.addActionListener(new ClearHandler(helper));
exit.addActionListener(new ExitHandler(helper));
search.addActionListener(new SearchHandler(helper));
```

A much better choice is to use `Action`s, thus providing necessary icons, shortcuts, etc to your buttons with the code of the handler. Read the Java tutorial.

Comment: So I can create all different inner classes for different action but still I can have inner classes in same MainWindow class?

Comment: Because, all the textFields and buttons are private in MainWIndow.

Comment: Yes you can have any number of inner class. What has to do with the fact that your buttons are private?

Comment: Sorry, i meant that if I didnt create inner class and went with other public classes then those components wont be available. SOrry for silly questions but I am new to GUI and I event handling is a new concept for me. Also i know i can create inner classes as much as I want.